# Unrecognized Guid format error in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello all I am facing this problem in asp.net project .
"System.FormatException: Unrecognized Guid format.
  at System.Guid.GuidResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String failureMessageID, Object failureMessageFormatArgument, String failureArgumentName, Exception innerException)
  at System.Guid.TryParseGuid(String g, GuidStyles flags, GuidResult& result)
  at System.Guid..ctor(String g)
  at UserAuthentication.HumanResources.ViewAllJobs() in HumanResources.cs:line 105"

my code and store procedure for HumanResource.cs is as follows
 First one is HumanResource code second is store procedure

```
       public static List<HumanResources> ViewAllJobs()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new       SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spHumanResourcesViewAllJobs", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        List<HumanResources> jobs = new List<HumanResources>();
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                HumanResources hr = new HumanResources();
                hr.jobTitle = rdr["JobTitle"].ToString();

               Guid guid = new Guid(rdr["Guid"].ToString());
                hr.guid = guid;
                jobs.Add(hr);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
        }
        return jobs;
    }


             Store Procedure:
                 CREATE PROCEDURE spHumanResourcesViewAllJobs 
         AS
           BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;


SELECT Guid,JobTitle
FROM HR
WHERE Active=1
```

END
GO

Comment: What does the result of `rdr["Guid"].ToString()` look like? Obviously it isn't a string that is recognized as a guid. Also, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ff78dc(v=vs.110).aspx) for expected formats.

Comment: What do u mean by result look like ?Kindly elaborate your question so that I can answer.

Comment: I mean what string do you get when you execute the statement `rdr["Guid"].ToString()`? Add a breakpoint in your code where you try to instantiate the guid and try typing that in the immediate window of the debugger. Obviously it *isn't* a guid (or at least one of them isn't). The error message here is pretty clear: `Unrecognized Guid format`

Comment: It gives me 32 bit 0000 string

Comment: 32 bit? Do you mean 32 characters? Is that always the case? You are doing this a loop and you only need one failed case to throw that exception. For the record, `new Guid("00000000000000000000000000000000");` will not throw an exception because that's a perfectly valid Guid. `new Guid("0000");`, of course, will throw an exception.

Comment: Yes I mean as you are saying But after implementing Owain correction it is not showing me the jobs I have in my database

Comment: Use valid guids in the first place. This is coming from your source data, you need to fix it.

Comment: can you please give me some example of how to fix it in source data.

Answer (score 3):

The error is on this line:

```
Guid guid = new Guid(rdr["Guid"].ToString());
```

You could put a guard clause in your code to not add `hr` objects if they do not have a valid guid:

```
Guid guid;
if (Guid.TryParse(rdr["Guid"].ToString(), out guid))
{
    hr.guid = guid;
    jobs.Add(hr);
}
```

Comment: Kindly tell me where to use it .

Comment: @user3061917: In place of the line that Owain highlighted as causing the problem. How you handle cases where the guid doesn't parse is up to you. You could add an `else` clause and do whatever makes sense there. But do any of them parse? If not, you need to figure that out first.

Comment: Owain I have tried your correction It worked but now it does not show me the jobs I have added in my page .what should I do now?

Comment: @user3061917: Probably because you are failing the `TryParse` (returns false) and not executing the `jobs.Add(hr)` part. You need to fix your guids so they are valid.

Comment: ok can you please tell me how to fix guids or define it ?so that It can work as I have searched alot and I could not find my answer.

Comment: You could try running another stored procedure that displays both the Guid and whether TryParse returned true or false, then select just the rows where it is false and see what the problem is. [Guid Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ff78dc(v=vs.110).aspx) shows the valid formats. My guess is you have some nulls, or null-length strings.

Comment: Another option would be to move the `jobs.Add(hr);` line below the closing brace, these will then be added to the collection, but with a guid of 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.